# Sending a 10GB mysql table to distant server

Tags: mysql, bash

I'm trying to export a large myisam table (10GB) to a distant server :

```
zcat mytable.sql.gz | mysql --host=xx --user=xx --port=xx --password=xx dw
```

Sending a gzip mysqldump fails systematically because of the distant server configuration (which I cannot change) and RAM.

I tried to build a dump with a single insert per line :

```
mysqldump db_name --extended-insert=FALSE --no-create-info=TRUE | gzip > mytable.sql.gz
```

And split it into 200M chunks :

```
split -C 200M --numeric-suffixes mytable.sql.gz /dumps/mytable_part
```

But sending one of these 200M chunks takes more than 20 minutes, so sending the whole table would be much too slow for a regular backup. I guess the one insert per line is very slow.

A solution could be to make multiple insert dumps but with grouped inserts like INSERT INTO (field) VALUES (1), (2), ... but I'm not sure if that's possible.

Is there a workaround I haven't thought about ?

Comment: Depending on distance and location, try and post an encrypted USB. `;-)`

Comment: Can I do that through CLI ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compress on the wire there's no need for a manual invocation of `gzip`, the  `-C` (shorthand for `--compress`) flag does just that with mysql (the `mysqldump db | mysql -C -h=remote`).

In case of Léa's answer, using `ssh -C` might speed up the transfer time.

In each case, I'd advise calling `mysqldump` with the `--lock-tables=false` flag in order to reduce the locking impact on the dumped db (a very wise thing to do on production systems)...

PS: This was supposed to be comment on [@Bill Karwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56856052/sending-a-10gb-mysql-table-to-distant-server/56877504#comment100270945_5685739)'s suggestion but it seems I don't have enough reputation to comment on a thread...

Answer (score 1):

```
mysqldump \
  --extended-insert=FALSE \
  --no-create-info=TRUE \
  db_name \
| ssh \
    username@remote-host.example.com \
    mysql \
      --user=xx \
      --password=xx \
      dw
```

How it works:

`mysqldump --extended-insert=FALSE --no-create-info=TRUE db_name`
Creates the MySQL dump of the `db_name` and streams the data into the `stdio` output.

`| ssh username@remote-host.example.com`
Pipes the `stdio` stream into the `ssh` connection to the remote-host

`mysql --user=xx --password=xx dw`
Is the `mysql` command executed at the remote-host by the `ssh` connection.
It reads the `stdio` stream that is being transmitted via the `ssh` connection and originating from the MySQL dump. That dump is generated locally, transmitted via `ssh` and imported at the remote-host into the dw database.

This method is preferred more secure and compact over opening the MySQL protocol to the wide internet that any competent admin will refuse to do.

This is probably why your first attempt with the `mysql` command directly addressing the remote-host would not work.
The remote-host MySQL database server is not listening or accepting remote connections, or at least not from the wide internet.

Using `ssh` alow you to securely transmit the dump data while having the remote-host's MySQL server only deal with local connection from the `mysql` command.

Comment: what does this do?

Comment: It dumps the MySQL database, pipes the dump through ssh to the remote host calling MySQL on the remote host to read data from the ssh-tunnel piped dump

Comment: @LéaGris Generally, including an explanation of *why* and *how* a code snippet helps solve the problem improves the quality and longevity of your answer. You may want to make an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56857394/edit) to include your comment. See ["How do I write a good answer?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @slothiful so I did

Comment: You could also gzip before the transfer: `mysqldump ... | gzip -c | ssh host 'gunzip -c  | mysql ...` which should decrease the transfer time.

Answer (score 0):

You might look into [`rsync`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) which is a ubiquitous delta-transfer algorithm with options for block size, attribute tracking, compression, and tunneling, however this won't help if your bottleneck is Disk I/O.